# Contact Layout Editor side by side columns

Tags: wordpress, contacts, contact-view, contact-layout-editor

When setting up a custom layout for contacts with the Contact Layout Editor extension, is there a way to setup certain fields (within a tab) side by side instead of on top of each other?

So this is how it looks now:
[image]

But this is what I want it to look like:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it using Search Kit and form builder.

Create a search using a search kit with a display as a grid, include the search in a form and enable the in a tab.